# How to figure out number of pairs of integers satisfying the inequality $xy<c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many integers $x$ and $y$ satisfy the inequality $xy<c$ given $x>0$ , $y>0$ and $c>0$ ?

Comment: Read about unique factorization theorem aka The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.

Comment: Write c = $p_1p_2\ldots p_n$, where the $p_i$ are all primes. Can you now see how to reformulate the question in a simpler way?

Comment: Sorry for mistake, actually the question is xy<c

Comment: Make your question more precise by asking e.g. for the number of *pairs of integers*.

Answer (score 1):

Since $xy$ can only be an integer, it is more convenient to write $xy\le n$  instead of $xy<c$ (set $n = \lceil c\rceil-1$ here). The number of pairs $(x,y)$ of positive integers for which this inequality holds is known as the [Divisor summatory function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function). On the Wikipedia page you will see that the leading terms of this function are known since Dirichlet: 
$$n\log n+(2\gamma-1)n + \text{remainder}$$
but the precise order of the remainder remains an open problem.